# Matrix / vectors notation

Tags: writing

Is there any **standard** to represent Matrix / vectors symbols like using bold fonts, bar, underline or arrow notation?

Comment: No. Totally (sub-)field dependent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to represent a tensor/matrix/vector/array in blackboard?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98257/how-to-represent-a-tensor-matrix-vector-array-in-blackboard)

Comment: Is there any standard... Technically yes, there is an [ISO standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11#Vectors_and_tensors). That said, Haudie's comment is correct, different fields do different things (and totally ignore it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different fields use different conventions. For instance, mathematicians frequently use lower case italic letters for vectors and upper case italic letters for matrices.

For physics and chemistry, IUPAP and IUPAC *recommend* (some journal guidelines are in agreement with this recommendation) a number of symbols for quantities that can be found in the following document:

[E R Cohen *et al.*, "Quantities, Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry", IUPAC Green Book, 3rd Edition, 2nd Printing, IUPAC & RSC Publishing, Cambridge, 2008](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf)

In particular, the document recommends to typeset matrices and vectors with a bold italic font.